How to move a layer to a group using Python code in ArcGIS Pro?
I am trying to move a layer to a group using python code. Both the layer and the group are in the current/same map in ArcGIS Pro.
I have the following code (the layer to be moved to the group "VMS" is "Fishnet_v1_manual")
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
mp = aprx.listMaps()[0]
lyr_to_move = mp.listLayers("Fishnet_v1_manual")
group_layer = mp.listLayers("VMS")
mp.addLayerToGroup(group_layer, lyr_to_move, "AUTO_ARRANGE")

But I keep getting this error:

I have also tried moving the layer to after the first layer in the group using moveLayer, but still get a similar error message as the above. The code I used for this is:
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
mp = aprx.listMaps()[0]
lyr_to_move = mp.listLayers("Fishnet_v1_FeatureLayer_v3")
ref_layer = mp.listLayers(r"Data points in grid")
mp.moveLayer(ref_layer, lyr_to_move, "AFTER")

The error message is:

Any ideas on how to fix this error or are there other ways of moving a layer to a group in the current map?

@Hornbydd - Thanks. Before posting, I did look at the help file for ArcGIS Pro https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm. "addLayerToGroup" has three parameters - 1) target_group_layer, 2)add_layer_or_layerfile and 3){add_position}. I have all the three specified in the code I shared above.  The helpfile for which you have provided a link is for ArcMap where AddLayerToGroup  has 4 parameters - data_frame, target_group_layer, add_layer
and {add_position}, but this is not the case in the 'addLayerToGroup' method in ArcGIS Pro.

Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than only in pictures.

The help file states that listLayers() - Returns a Python list of Layer objects that exist within a map.
So in your code lyr_to_move is a list object.
To retrieve the layer from the list to feed into the addLayerToGroup() you would use the following code:
lyr_to_move = mp.listLayers("Fishnet_v1_manual")[0]


Hi, Thanks for this. I accordingly updated the code to:
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
mp = aprx.listMaps()[0]
lyr_to_move = mp.listLayers("Fishnet_v1_manual")[0]
group_layer = mp.listLayers("VMS")[0]
mp.addLayerToGroup(group_layer, lyr_to_move, " AUTO_ARRANGE")
The above works fine. One thing to check – this code copies the "Fishnet_v1_manual" layer into the "VMS" group rather than moving it. Is there a way to move (i.e. not copy) the layer into the group? I can see "moveLayer" achieves this but then it does not work with moving a layer into a group.

As you have a handle on the layer object after it is copied into the group layer you could simply remove it with removeLayer()?

This is what I am doing. But I wanted to check if  - similar to moveLayer (which does not copy but just moves the layer) - there is a one-step of moving a layer to a group instead of  two steps: 1) adding the layer to the group, and 2) removing that layer from outside the group.
